# Spring security timeout handler

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I'm using Spring/JSF/PrimeFaces web application wherein it has session timeout set,

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

and in spring security

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/faces/ui/login.xhtml" use-expressions="true">

<form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
    login-page="/faces/ui/Login.xhtml" 
    default-target-url="/faces/ui/FirstPage.xhtml" 
    authentication-failure-url="/faces/ui/Login.xhtml" 
    authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />

<logout invalidate-session="true" 
    logout-success-url="/faces/ui/Login.xhtml" 
    delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
    logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>

<session-management invalid-session-url="/faces/ui/Login.xhtml">
    <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="2" expired-url="/faces/ui/Login.xhtml" />
</session-management>

 <beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="com.app.spring.security.AppSecurityUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

How to add listener for timeout in springsecurity, this is required for

1. Perform some custom actions on session invalidation
2. Redirect to Login page, after timeout(both ajax and non-ajax
   requests)

Using

- Spring-3.1.1.RELEASE
- JSF 2.1.11
- PrimeFaces-4.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Why are you interested in using PrimeFaces-4.0-SNAPSHOT? :)

Comment: That's not the issue.. will be upgraded soon.